# How to get interface method name as String?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'd like to get an interface method name as String. Here is my code. It's a Spring Batch reader.

```java
  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Data> reader() {
    var sorts = new HashMap<String, Direction>();
    sorts.put("id", Direction.ASC);

    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Data>()
        .name("dataReader")
        .repository(dataRepository)
        .methodName("myCustomMethod")
        .arguments("latest")
        .sorts(sorts)
        .build();
  }
```

As you can see I have a `dataRepository` interface that has a method `myCustomMethod`. I'm currently using the handwritten String as the `methodName` method argument. I was wondering if I could somehow get the name as a String via Java, e.g. something like (pseudo code)

```java
        .methodName(dataRepository.myCustomMethod.getName())
```

That does not work and I'm getting an error.

```
myCustomMethod cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

My problem is that the manually entered String is not really save when it comes to refactoring. I could simply remove the `myCustomMethod` and the compiler would not complain. I'd like to have this safety during compile time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have multiple methods in that interface or just 1?

Comment: No there isn't. You could use reflection but that still would need a `String` method name and wouldn't work compile time either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use introspection/reflection (don't remeber what's the exact word in English). But basically you could do something like this to get all the methods:

`IDoable.class.getMethods()`

Then you can just iterate over the array and do

`method.GetName()`

Also, you just need to iterate if needed. But if you, for example, need the name of the 2nd method of an interface, you can simplify this to :

`IDoable.class.getMethods()[1].getName()`

Comment: afaik, there is no guaranteed ordering (anymore) when using reflection so results could vary between runs. Also this wouldn't be a compile time thing which validates the method but also runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In case your interface only has 1 method, you could fetch the method name using reflection like:

```java
dataRepository.getClass().getMethods[0].getName()
```